# Find material for improvement of my SQL ability

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need lots of training in SQL coding in MS SQL server

The following part that is needed to be improved is:

- script
- T SQL
- Procedure
- Function

Problem:
Where can I get material to improve my ability in SQL coding? Is there any website for downloading a database with different task/assignment and solution?

Where should I go to review lots of SQL code?

Comment: Use SQL in a non-trivial application with a SQL-powered database as a backend?

Answer (score 3):

You can download and install the [Northwind and Pubs sample database](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/northwind/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1401).

This is used in many tutorials and examples on MSDN.

Then, start reading through [Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130214.aspx) about the topics you have difficulties with. Play around with the databases.

Answer (score 0):

You can get some help from tutorials such as ones available at [Fianga](http://www.fianga.com/) and [Function X](http://www.functionx.com).

From Fianga:

> Microsoft SQL Server is a computer
>   application used to create desktop,
>   enterprise, and web-based database
>   applications. It is used at different
>   levels and with various goals. This
>   web site provides lessons and topics
>   on how to use Microsoft SQL Server
>   2008 to create and manage databases.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be directly realated to your question but if your looking for different SQL problems and techniques to solve them i would suggest having a look at some books by Joe Celko.

- thinking in Sets: Auxiliary, Temporal
  and Virtual Tables in SQL
- Trees and    Hierarchies in SQL for
  Smarties SQL
- Puzzles and Answers

He does have some other titles but these should cover most areas in the usage of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to prepare for MS exam 70-433. Use suggested books.

Comment: Which book do you suggest in order to read MS exam 70-433?

Comment: I passed sql exam 10 years ago, so don't really know current "state of art". However books recommended as training material 10 years ago were useful. So I guess for instance this one:    http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/book.aspx?ID=13159&locale=en-us   should be good.

Answer (score 0):

The textbook I've been using, Microsoft T-SQL Fundamentals, comes with a sample database and sample questions (with solutions). I highly recommend the book.

Browsing StackOverflow for SQL questions has been useful for me. [This custom link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql+OR+sql-server+OR+sql-server-2008+OR+query+OR+ssms+OR+ssms2008+OR+tsql+OR+sql-server-2005) I use has most of the SQL tags (specifically SQL Server) for easy browsing.

Lastly, try the links mentioned in this question.
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49942/website-with-sql-exercises-and-solutions

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn about using functions and a lot of other t-sql knowledge, I can't recommend [Transact SQL User Defined Functions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1556220790) by Andrew Novick enough. Everything from design to formating. Before starting this book, you should have a basic understanding of sql. Probably one of the better programming books I've ever read.